# What is taking time on IIS, if it is not my code? Are request queued?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented a number of services in asp.net Web API.
I have implemented an ActionFilterAttribute to measure the performance on the server:

```
public class PerformanceActionFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Request.Properties[StopwatchKey] = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var stopwatch = (Stopwatch) actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties[StopwatchKey];
        if(actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("ServerTimeMs", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

The above code sends the time spend on the server back to the client as a header. This header shows very nice performance for all service calls. Usually below 100 ms. 
When the load on the server grows I keep getting nice performance from the above measurements, but the performance I experience in the browser is bad.
I get "waiting times" above 10 seconds. Even with a fairly low load as seen from this screen shot from Chrome:

[image: Network tab in chrome]

I'm using a windows server 2012.

My conclusion so far is that it is not my code that takes a long time to execute. But what is it then? And how do I investigate this problem?

(I have also tried measuring the performance using `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` in Global.asax. It gives roughly the same values.)

Edit:
Some additional info from a random request recorded by fiddler. Note the long gap between `ClientConnected` and `ClientBeginRequest`:

```
ClientConnected:    19:20:58.835
ClientBeginRequest: 19:21:06.928
GotRequestHeaders:  19:21:06.928
ClientDoneRequest:  19:21:06.928
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect:     0ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    19:20:53.769
FiddlerBeginRequest:19:21:06.928
ServerGotRequest:   19:21:06.929
ServerBeginResponse:19:21:07.043
GotResponseHeaders: 19:21:07.043
ServerDoneResponse: 19:21:07.043
ClientBeginResponse:19:21:07.043
ClientDoneResponse: 19:21:07.043
```

Comment: Could it be my pc that cannot handle the task of sending this many requests? I'm using visual studio load test to stress test the services. This page describes connection reuse. http://fiddler.wikidot.com/timers.
"ClientBeginRequest– Time at which this HTTP request began. May be much later than ClientConnected due to client connection reuse"

Comment: According to those Fiddler times, the request was sent with extreme delay and the server answered quickly. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a closer look at the performance counters on the server, I can see that the execution time is in fact very low. But around 400 request pr. second the IIS starts queueing the requests.

So the answer to my question must be that apart from executing my code, the request is spending a lot of time in a queue. The queue starts building up, but the execution time of each request is still very low.

This leads to a new question. How to optimize my application or the server setup to push the limit. But that's another story.

Comment: This does not seem to explain the problem. IIS does not queue if the server is unloaded. You haven't responded to my comment yet: It looks like the client is just not issuing requests quickly.

Comment: The client is issuing requests very fast. And they are handled by the server very fast. Up until around 400 request pr sec. The time spent between Request_Begin and Request_End stays low the whole time but the ASP.NET performance counter "Request Queued" starts to increase. And the response times as experienced on the client starts to increase at this point as well. So it definitely looks like the request spends most of the time in a queue. The fiddler numbers are just confusing the picture because of the connection reuse.

Comment: With various optimizations of my code I have been able to increase the number of requests pr sec I can reach before the queue starts building up.

Comment: OK, those new numbers indeed support your theory. Are you interested in working more on this problem or is it resolved for you?

Comment: The performance that I'm getting now is acceptable. And most important: I trust the numbers I get from my load test. It could be interesting to investigate what causes the IIS to start queueing, and what needs to be done to get even higher requests pr. sec before the queue builds up. Should I fix things in my code or should I look at the configuration of the IIS? Or is this the max request pr sec I can expect with the current hardware and the complexity of the solution? But I do not have time to go into more details for now. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Yeah, I was intrigued by that as well. Either the limits are set too low or your CPU is maxed out.